# How to calculate Cron Job type time c#

Tags: c#, cron

I want to calculate how much minute left to arrive next Cron Job time .

```
//Cron Job data from sql timer list elements 
//first
TimerMinute = "*"
TimerHour = "*/12"
TimerDay = "*"
TimerMonth = "*"
TimerWeekDay = "*"
//second
TimerMinute = "30"
TimerHour = "8-18"
TimerDay = "29"
TimerMonth = "10"
TimerWeekDay = "*"

calculate(list[0]);
calculate(list[1]);

public void calculateAndRun(string[] list)
{
    //needed code
    callThisMethodWhenYouNeedToCall();
    callThisMethodIfElementHaveInterval();
    //if need more method can be use every skils of cron job
}
```

first element call this method every 12 hours

```
callThisMethodWhenYouNeedToCall();
```

second element call this method every 29.October 8:30

```
callThisMethodWhenYouNeedToCall();
```

and second element call this method when time 18:30 at 29.October

```
callThisMethodIfElementHaveInterval();
```

Comment: Maybe you can clarify a bit more what you need?

Comment: basicly i have cron job list and i need timer

Comment: so you want to re-implement cron with C#?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-implement cron in C# have a look at [this Github project](https://github.com/kevincolyar/CronNET) and how [this method](https://github.com/kevincolyar/CronNET/blob/master/CronNET/CronSchedule.cs#L72) works.

Comment: I have cronNet but i couldn't figgure out how to use .What should i do . can u give me an example . I have a list at cron format. I can generate and sent it a function . But which function ? so i have a generated date and i need a timer can understand and do cron format